# Attempting to get exit codes from children shells, after a call to Win32::Process::Create

Tags: perl, winapi, multiprocessing, exit-code

Why does the following output `0` and not `4`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Win32::Process qw( NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS INFINITE );

Win32::Process::Create(my $ProcessObj,
   $ENV{COMSPEC},
   $ENV{COMSPEC}.' /c start /min perl -e"sleep 5; exit 4"',
   0,
   NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
   '.',
)
   or die $^E;

$ProcessObj->Wait(INFINITE);
$ProcessObj->GetExitCode(my $exit_code);
say $exit_code;  # 0
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - what about why I'm not seeing the ERROR IN BUILD text though, at the end of the process, when it's clearly `2` when I print it from within the inner script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you are executing is `cmd`. Its exit code is the exit code of the last command it executes.

The last program `cmd` executes is `start`, which launches a program and exits. Its exit code is *not* the exit code of the program it launched. How could it be? It might not even have started executing yet, much less exit.

To best way to get the script's exit code is if it's your own child. Don't use `cmd` and `start`; launch the program directly with the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag. I don't know how to minimize it, though, but you'll have to search for that. (We can help you create a Perl solution if none exist and you find out how to do it in C.)

Comment: Thank you, this seems so obvious now

Comment: I've changed my 2 lines to: $cmd = "compile.pl $dir $semaCompile $log $semaLogName $compileType $skipPDB";
  Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,"C:\\Perl64\\bin\\wperl.exe",$cmd,0,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,".");

But now, I just get an error of 9 printed for everything. Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: The third argument should be the command. Does using the correct command (`"C:\\Perl64\\bin\\wperl.exe compile.pl ..."`) help?

Comment: Anyway, you're being extremely unclear again. "Everything printing error 9"? Please!!!